# Audio Web player на python

Tags: python, web-audio

Нужно написать Audio Web player, чтобы разместить его на сайт. Видел много вариантов и уроков на js, но очень хотелось бы реализовать это на python (+ xhtml, html, css).

Подскажите материалы, примеры, или советы.

А еще, где хранить аудио и как подключать к бд?

Comment: В качестве сервера попробуйте flask, базой можно использовать sqlite, плеер, я так понимаю, нужно среди библиотек на js смотреть

Comment: Охх уж этот js, походу без него никак, что ж посмотрим что еще скажут. Списибо)

Comment: Если вам простой плейер нужен, можно попробовать воспользоваться тэгом audio HTML5. Ему достаточно будет передавать то что вы хотите прослушивать при помощи того же flask.

Comment: Думаю так и будет, но тогда остается вопрос хранения данных. В каком выде их хранить в бд? Например, прямая сылка на песню как string или unicode? или еще что-то?

Comment: «прямая сылка на песню как string или unicode?» — да, как вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое исследование этого вопроса привело к следующим выводам.
Если хочу сделать web audio player, то без UI не обойтись.
В back-end на python можно отнести все что касается плейлистов, учета, выбора.
Воспроизводить придется клиенту или браузеру, поэтому без js пока никак.

Но вопрос все еще открыт, и если у вас есть отличное предложение, буду рад почитать и узнать новое.